# Install meteorite/mrt don't work on Mac osx

Tags: meteor, meteorite

Here is what I did on my mac:

```
brew install npm
sudo -H npm install -g meteorite
```

The outcome is:

```
 $ sudo -H npm install -g meteorite
    Password:
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/meteorite
    ....

    > meteorite@0.6.13 postinstall /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/meteorite
    > sh ./completions/postinstall.sh

    npm WARN package.json node@0.0.0 No repository field.
    meteorite@0.6.13 /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/meteorite
    ├── colors@0.6.0-1
    ├── underscore@1.5.2
    ├── wrench@1.5.1
    ├── fstream@0.1.24 (inherits@2.0.1, graceful-fs@2.0.1, rimraf@2.2.2, mkdirp@0.3.5)
    ├── optimist@0.6.0 (wordwrap@0.0.2, minimist@0.0.5)
    ├── ddp@0.3.4 (meteor-ejson@0.6.3, ws@0.4.31)
    └── prompt@0.2.11 (revalidator@0.1.5, pkginfo@0.3.0, read@1.0.5, utile@0.2.0, winston@0.6.2)
```

But when I type `mrt`,it shows

```
$ mrt
-bash: mrt: command not found
```

My node and nom version are :

```
$ node -v
v0.10.12
$ npm -v
1.2.32
```

Anyone help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the reason and solution: the `mrt` in ~/node_modules/meteorite/.bin/  should be included in /usr/local/bin or somewhere in  your $PATH environment.So do this:

```
cp ~/node_modules/meteorite/.bin/mrt /usr/local/bin/
```

When I type `mrt`,it works:)

Comment: For other readers, my path (Mac Os X 10.8) is `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`

Comment: My path (OS X 10.9) is /usr/local/share/npm/bin/mrt